# Java platform SE has stopped working when client(android) calls the server

Tags: android, client-server

javaw.exe crashes when the communication between client and server is going on.

It does not show any pattern as it crashes anytime,and many times it does not crashes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.exe instead of javaw to get a windows trace at least. And use exceptions purposefully. Don't let any catch clause empty, you could even use a UncaughtExceptionHandler to know where things break.

Don't panic, Java is a *very* robust language.

Comment: it doesn't lead to a crash but prevents you from getting a stack trace in a console. And don't call people sire here Saint, it's a very friendly place, not hierarchical. Show your respect to people by beeing polite, offering your time to answer and help. Did you look at UncaughtExceptionHandler ?

Comment: What you can do then is having a try catch(Throwable ex) inside your main server loop. Log the throwable and make sure your server will remain up and running if something happens. Catching a throwable is not a very good programming practice but it will help to determine what 's going wrong and later you can catch finer exceptions